# How do I left-align the hamburger menu in Foundation

Tags: html, css, menu, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using SASS, which I'm brand new to, but I'm running into problems. From the documentation, it sounded like I needed to edit _top-bar.scss and add a line that says: $topbar-menu-icon-position: $default-float; (as opposed to $opposite-direction;).

But that doesn't seem to work -- the hamburger menu icon continues to be right aligned on mobile.

I'm pretty sure the issue isn't with the HTML code, but just in case:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">Name</a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
      <a href="#"><span>menu</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss)

you will see a top bar position

```
   $topbar-menu-icon-position: $opposite-direction !default; // Change to $default-float for a left menu icon
```

essentially you need to change it to

```
  $topbar-menu-icon-position: $default-float !default;
```

I suggest adding that to your local sass and not edit the original file so that you can easily upgrade in the future.